# Default version for API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have enabled versioning for Azure API Management (APIM).  The versioning is based on querystring parameters (e.g. `?api-version=1.0`).  The intent for using a querystring is so that if the user doesn't provide the parameter, it'll default to the latest version.  So:

```
/api/operation?api-version=1.0 <- Goes to 1.0
/api/operation?api-version=1.1 <- Goes to 1.1
/api/operation                 <- Goes to 1.1 (assuming that is latest)
```

However, it appears as though APIM uses that parameter as an indexer and if it's not provided, APIM doesn't know which version to use.  Is there a way to tell APIM that, if the parameter is missing, automatically go to a specific version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible in Azure APIM. API version is required to be passed for every request.

Comment: After much looking, this answer has become painfully evident.  Hopefully Microsoft makes this possible in the future.  I have marked this as the correct answer for future developers.

Comment: I'm running into the same thing, for my query string version scheme. Tried to solve this with 'set-query-parameter' policy in the global inbound policy, but that didn't work. To me that would be a logical location to set a default when the version in the query string is missing. Can you explain why this doesn't work?

Comment: Version number is not just metadata for your call, it's a part of your URL that identifies your API. Setting it in policy will not work because it's already too late in request processing pipeline to change anything about which API is executed when policies are at work. Different API versions have different policies, so version has to be identified for policy to be executed. And if version is identified, then it's too late to change it for ongoing request.

Answer (score 1):

Once you opt into API versioning, all API routes are explicitly versioned. This means a client cannot request a resource without explicitly providing an API version.

In order to make your scenario work, you need to allow match a default API version when a client doesn't specify anything. You could set up like below:

```
service.AddApiVersioning( options => options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true );
```

The `AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified` option enables support for clients to make requests with implicit API versioning. This option is **disabled by default**, which means that all clients must send requests with an explicit API version. 
Services will respond to client requests that do not specify an API version with either HTTP status code `400 (Bad Request)` or HTTP status code `404 (Not Found)`, depending whether the requested route exists.

Also, you could use `DefaultApiVersion` option which defines what the default ApiVersion will be for a service without explicit API version information. **The default configured value is 1.0**.

```
services.AddApiVersioning(
    o => o.DefaultApiVersion =
        new ApiVersion( new DateTime( 2016, 7, 1 ) );
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/API-Versioning-Options).

Comment: I have previously used this technique and it works very well.  The issue is that it means that versioning is handled by the API itself and not really through Azure API Management (making APIM redundant).  This technique doesn't work with APIM versioning enabled because the request never makes it to your API.  My hope was to leave the versioning exclusively up to APIM and achieve the same thing.  That notwithstanding, your answer is absolutely correct for those not looking to use APIM.