# Default Routing to latest version with APIM

Tags: api, azure-functions, azure-api-management

I have similar question as in this questions [Default version for API Management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52301436/default-version-for-api-management)

However the question is old, had there been any recent changes in APIM which allows this behaviour where if you dont pass any versions in header/path/query it routes to latest versions

```
/api/operation?api-version=1.0 <- Goes to 1.0

/api/operation?api-version=1.1 <- Goes to 1.1

/api/operation                 <- Goes to 1.1 (Here 1.1. is the latest and if no version is pass in URI it should route to latest one(1.1 in this case))
```

In my case we are using Azure Function for backend API.

Just to add I am not able to comment on existing question :(

Comment: Joey Kai answer doesn't work?

Comment: @AntonKomyshan Joey Kai is an option but it is at Backend API level. I was looking something at APIM side

Answer (score 1):

Still the same behavior, you have to provide the Api version. When you add a version to a non-versioned API, an Original version will be automatically created and will respond on the default URL so if you do not provide an Api version the original version will respond to that call.

Comment: So here 'Original' could be used as latest version. Is their anyway we could rename this 'original' one as 'latest'?

Comment: What do you mean by rename, just the name shows up in Azure portal, if yes, I think you can do it from the Api settings